# Fresco doesn't show image

Tags: android, fresco

I'm trying to show image in `RecyclerView` using Fresco. I have image in my file system and i want to display it in `SimpleDraweeView` by image location in `String` format. But in this view i have empty image. Log doesn't show any error. Can anyone help me? Here's my code where i'm trying to set the image:

```
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (new File(imageData.getLocation()).exists()){
        Uri fileLocationUri = Uri.parse("file:/" + imageData.getLocation());
        ImageRequest request = ImageRequest.fromUri(fileLocationUri);
        DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setImageRequest(request)
                .setOldController(imageView.getController())
                .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
                .build();
        imageView.setController(controller);
    }
```

Image location is a string, which started with `/`, so Uri parser returns correct result. XML file:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        a:id = "@+id/outgoing_photo_view"
        a:layout_width="300dp"
        a:layout_height="300dp"
        a:adjustViewBounds="true"
        a:visibility="gone"
        fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
        fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="fitCenter"
        fresco:failureImageScaleType="centerInside"
        fresco:retryImageScaleType="centerCrop"
        fresco:roundAsCircle="false"
        fresco:roundedCornerRadius="1dp"
        fresco:roundTopLeft="true"
        fresco:roundTopRight="false"
        fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
        fresco:roundBottomRight="true"
        fresco:roundingBorderWidth="2dp"/>
```

Comment: Could it be because you have visibility set to gone on the SimpleDraweeView?

Comment: @VishnuM. in code i set visibility to visible. I have empty square, but i have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your file URI is not valid.

It should work with something like this:

```
File file = ... // your file
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file); // to get a valid file:// URI
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
        .setUri(uri)
        .build();
```

Comment: It's work, but i have very strong freezes while scrolling images. Profiler says that `Uri.fromFile()` take so much reources

Comment: Ideally you should prepare the URI and controller beforehand.

Take a look at this example adapter for a list of local images: [LocalResourceSimpleAdapter](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/scrollperf/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/scrollperf/data/impl/LocalResourceSimpleAdapter.java)

It has 2 variants for lazy loading or creating the URIs beforehand - see `mLazy`.